# Prices of products (only some products) not updating on front end

Tags: magento-1.7, price, product-prices, custom-prices

I have changed prices of products in my store, checked it on the website and some of them have been changed but some not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many store do you have right now?

If you have multi store. Please check once have you set the price for that store which store product you are seeing at frontend.

Also Please do indexing from magento admin panel.

Comment: Hi Soumik Rana, 
I've checked the product and it is in right store (this one is visible only in one store). Then I went to System>Index Management and reindexed all indexes. I refreshed the front end page and the prices are still old ones. 
Weird is that correct prices are showing in Magento back end but not on front end.

Comment: Please edit and save any one of the product from the admin panel which have price issue. and then what is happening at frontend also don't forgot to index?

Comment: Okay so I open the product in admin section, I go to 'Price' and change price - this works perfect! 
Then I go to 'Custom Options' and I change price there (it doesn't ask me to reindex anything after I press save), the price is changed in admin section but when I check website, it is still old price.

Comment: Please check with firebug at frontend any jquery or prototype error is there?

Comment: There is no error apart from 'Typekit: the domain "***********" isn't in the list of published domains for kit "**********".' which I don't think it has anything to do with prices.